# Jenkins how to have post-build to use previous build's workspace

Tags: testing, build, jenkins

I have two build jobs. The first cleans&builds the project (polling from SVN), and triggers a test build as a post-build action. I don't want to have the test build to poll the stuff from SVN again, so how do I have the test job to test the project using the binaries build in the previous build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your artifacts from 1 job to another using [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the result of builds (the artifacts) outside of Jenkins' area -
this will allow you to access them from any job, and even from other systems.